# How to create an api with FastAPI and scrapy?

Tags: python-requests, scrapy, fastapi, uvicorn

I am working on a web application project which will allow user to search from keywords and get a set of results based on the keywords entered from scraping. For this I use scrapy for scraping results from a web search engine. I wrote some code to pass the keywords to the scrapy file and display the scrapy results on a webpage. However, I'm having trouble passing the keywords to scrapy using FastAPI, because when I run my api code, I always get a set of errors from Scrapy. Here is the gist containing the runtime terminal [output](https://gist.github.com/gouneken/8542b1c5228c6f80490cf3e6a15e1110). I don't understand the problem, yet my scrapy code was working perfectly before I connected it to the api, I'm a beginner on creating APIs, so I ask for your help. Here is the code for my web scraper:

```
import scrapy
import datetime
from requests_html import HTMLSession 

class PagesearchSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'pageSearch'


    def start_requests(self,query):
        #queries = [ 'investissement']
        #for query in queries:
            url = f'https://www.ask.com/web?q={query}'
            s = HTMLSession()
            r = s.get
            print(r.status_code)
            qlist[""]
            
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': 0})




    def parse(self, response):

        print('url:', response.url)
        
        start_pos = response.meta['pos']
        print('start pos:', start_pos)

        dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')    
        
        items = response.css('div.PartialSearchResults-item')
        
        for pos, result in enumerate(items, start_pos+1):
            yield {
                'title':    result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link::text').get().strip(), 
                'snippet':  result.css('p.PartialSearchResults-item-abstract::text').get().strip(), 
                'link':     result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link').attrib.get('href'), 
                'position': pos, 
                'date':     dt,
            }

            qlist.append(items)

        # --- after loop ---
        
        next_page = response.css('.PartialWebPagination-next a')
        
        if next_page:
            url = next_page.attrib.get('href')
            print('next_page:', url)  # relative URL
            # use `follow()` to add `https://www.ask.com/` to URL and create absolute URL
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': pos+1})


# --- run without project, and save in file ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'test.json': {'format': 'json'}},
    #'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,  # this stop scraping
})
c.crawl(PagesearchSpider)
c.start()
```

the code allowing the functioning of my api:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from script import PagesearchSpider

app = FastAPI()
request = PagesearchSpider()

@app.get("/{cat}")
async def read_item(cat):
    return request.start_requests('cat')
```

I changed part of my scraper code, viz:

```
def start_requests(self,query):
        #queries = [ 'investissement']
        #for query in queries:
            url = f'https://www.ask.com/web?q={query}'
            
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                                        s = HTMLSession()
                                        r = s.get
                                        print(r.status_code)
                                        qlist[""]
```

but I still get the same errors. Unless I got the wrong crawler code, I'm not very good at scrapy
I also rewrote the code below my function...

```
# --- run without project, and save in file ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    #'FEEDS': {'test.json': {'format': 'json'}},
    #'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,  # this stop scraping
})
    c.crawl(PagesearchSpider)
    c.start()
```

and I executed this command `python -m uvicorn main:app --reload` to start server and I had the following results in the command line :

```
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\AAprojects\\Whelpsgroups1\\searchApi\\apiFast']
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Uvicorn running on ←[1mhttp://127.0.0.1:8000←[0m (Press CTRL+C to quit)
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Started reloader process [←[36m←[1m10956←[0m] using ←[36m←[1mstatreload←[0m
←[33mWARNING←[0m:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Started server process [←[36m6724←[0m]
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Waiting for application startup.
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Application startup complete.
←[33mWARNING←[0m:  StatReload detected file change in 'main.py'. Reloading...
←[33mWARNING←[0m:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Started server process [←[36m2720←[0m]
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Waiting for application startup.
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Application startup complete.
```

But when I click from the command line on the link of the address my server started at, it opens my file explorer on windows 10 and when I manually write that link i.e. `http://127.0.0.0:8000/` in my browser search bar it says `127.0.0.0` took too long to respond. Yet I didn't change any of my files, just the command I was using in console line so I don't know why this error.

I looked at the stack overflow questions, but they weren't directly related to the problem of difficulty sharing data between an api and a web scraper and on the internet I couldn't find any relevant answers. So I hope you could help me, I look forward to your answers, thank you!

Comment: The error message seems to be from the code you have at the bottom of your crawler code (i.e. instantiating the crawler in your crawler file). Wrap this code in a `if __name__ == '__main__`:` section to only have it run if you invoke the file directly.  Please include the error message _in your question_ instead of external links - external links can disappear at any time and makes the question less valuable in the future.

Comment: I modified my crawler code and got the same problem unless I got the code wrong, I put the details in my question

Comment: That's not what I meant. The part after `# --- run without project, and save in file ---` is the code that should be wrapped under the if-guard (if everything is present in a single file). It doesn't really make sense to have it inside a function.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still nothing, more detail in my question

Comment: You have to indent _everything_ below your if properly, otherwise it won't be part of the if-check (which is where you define `c`).

Comment: I also tried to indent  `c` but when I do that, and run `python main.py`  in terminal, I get no response whether error or otherwise, that's why I left  `c` blank indent it

Comment: You start your FastAPI instance in that case - you do not run the `main.py` file manually (unless that's the file that starts uvicorn - you haven't given any details about the file names).

Comment: I don't use `uvicorn `, just `fastapi`  `requests`   and `scrapy ` . And `main.py ` is my api file and my api folder only have two files that `main.py` api and   `scrapy` one scrapy except the automatically generated file

Comment: `uvicorn` is used to run your fastapi application; without a compatible asgi server there isn't any way to run your fastapi application.

Comment: ok, instead of  `python main.py `, i used the command `python -m uvicorn main:app --reload` but it doesn't work as expected because i have a problem connecting to the server after it started more details in my question

Comment: For my POV insert the Scrapy framework into and endpoint it's a little bit complex, could you use ```python requests```? and maybe a proxy rotator & html parsers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that and I'm already using python requests can you enlighten me a bit on proxy rotators and does that mean I won't be using scrapy anymore